# Query splunk from nagios

Tags: splunk, nagios

Currently we have an Splunk alarm for a system in my team however since the organization I'm currently in use Nagios as its official alarm system and it is an micro-service with a several nodes per service the solution we would like to have is a way to query Splunk via shell script or other Nagios integrations and create an Nagios alarm from the result. However I feel like my duckduckgo skills have let me down for find such a "solution" is it someone who done something like this or is it just seen as idiotic?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/ecentria/splunk-search-nagios-check ?

Comment: You most definitely *can* have a remote process hit the REST endpoint for Splunk - but without knowing what you want to find...it's going to be hard to help you get anywhere :)

Comment: looks like something in the right direction. Need to investigate further.